# Chimp on travis for meteor testing

Tags: javascript, meteor, travis-ci

I'm trying to implement a testing framework into my meteor [open source application](https://github.com/rsercano/mongoclient). Since [velocity](https://github.com/meteor-velocity/velocity) is deprecated for the meteorJS and they [recommend](https://forums.meteor.com/t/super-fast-3rd-generation-reactive-testing-with-chimp/14861) using [Chimp](https://github.com/xolvio/chimp), I'm trying to write it's travis.yml file.

First of all I don't have any tests yet. I'm just trying to make [my build](https://travis-ci.org/rsercano/mongoclient) green. My .travis.yml file so far:

```
sudo: required
language: node_js
node_js: 
  - 0.12
install: 
  - curl https://install.meteor.com | /bin/sh
  - meteor update
  - npm install -g chimp
script: 
  - meteor
  - chimp --ddp=http://localhost:3000 --watch --path=tests
env:
  - SELENIUM_BROWSER=phantomjs
```

But of course this doesn't work since meteor blocks the terminal as soon as it starts. Therefore, this script never goes to line that starts with chimp.

Any help would be appreciated to use chimp on travis..

Thanks

Comment: Does `meteor &` work? It'll spawn the process in the background, so other steps may continue

Comment: Here's the log of build with `meteor &` https://travis-ci.org/rsercano/mongoclient/builds/112867423

Comment: The problem of this command it will work as a daemon and I cant understand when it has started to use chimp command on. As you can guess chimp is dependent of meteor's startup.

Comment: You can (a) wait, say, 10 seconds, or (b) try `meteor | awk '{print} /=> App running at:/ {system("chimp -ddp=" $5 " --watch --path=tests")}'`, which will forward all output and run `chimp` when it detects the "app running at" line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New version of meteor has test command now !

```
sudo: false

language: node_js

before_install:
  - curl https://install.meteor.com | /bin/sh
  - export PATH="$HOME/.meteor:$PATH"

script:
  - meteor build $HOME/build.tgz

cache:
  directories:
    - node_modules

before_script:
  - meteor npm install

script:
  - meteor add dispatch:mocha-phantomjs
  - meteor test --once --driver-package dispatch:mocha-phantomjs
```